# Is it possible to build an editable (in wp-admin) drop down menu in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, menu, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to build a drop down menu which content (the text inside the `<li>` tags) can be edited and modified by the user (within wp-admin)?

(or is there any plugin for that?)

For instance, like the text inside the drop down menu in this page: http://melbournecandy.com/day-tours-dates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress has a built in feature called Menus which was developed by Woothemes. If you know HTML and CSS, you should be able to make such a dropdown menu yourself.

There's a JQuery plugin called Droppy I love that changes any HTML menu to a dropdown menu. Just remember to style it with CSS.

http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/droppy/

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/droppy